# ListView TextBlock context menu is not invoking the bound command

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

My `ListView` is binded to `ObservableDictionary` source. In `ListView` control, value is bound to `TextBlock`. The context menu for `TextBlock` is bound to an event but the event is not being executed on click. Below is the code.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Source, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Height="300">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}">
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Delete">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path= MenuClicked}" CommandParameter="Delete"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Rename">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path= MenuClicked}" CommandParameter="Rename"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path= MenuClicked}" CommandParameter="Add"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Import">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path= MenuClicked}" CommandParameter="Import"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide a `RelativeSource` for your CommandBinding. Something like

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuClicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource.FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="Delete"/>
```

Replace the `AncestoryType=Window` with `AncestoryType=UserControl` if your `ListView` is inside a `UserControl`

Answer (score 0):

**ContextMenu doesn't get same NameScope as in the `UIElement` they are defined.**

So binding (like ElementName, Ancestor) usually creates the problem. You have to set Name scope first in the code behind:

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(contextMenu, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

`contextMenu` is the `x:Name` of your context menu.

Then you can use relative source binding or any other binding for command. like below:

```
Command="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x: type ListView}},Path=DataContext.MenuClicked}"
```

**PS:** If `MenuClicked` command is defined in the DataContext of `ListView`.